# Тело цикла в JS выполняется только один раз

Tags: javascript, html

Предупреждение: не бить, я дня три как постигаю фронтенд и представляю, как могут абсурдно выглядеть мои каракули :)

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= form.num.value; i++)
{
  parent.innerHTML = '<div class="block">child</div>';
}
```

Счётчик ходит правильно (проверено), но тело выполняется только один раз.
[image: скрин из браузера]

Мб это  такой прикол js, что такая конструкция только один раз срабатывает, а может, я что-то пропустил, в любом случае, хотелось бы найти какую-нибудь альтернативу.
Вроде нормально работал вариант с createElement('div') и appendChild, но там на меня так и не снизошло, как прописать такому счастью класс.
Заранее благодарю за попытки наставить меня на путь истинный :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...тело выполняется только один раз...

Оно выполняется многократно, но каждый раз innerHTML принимает одинаковое значение `<div class="block">child</div>`

Можно было внутри цикла написать

`parent.innerHTML += '<div class="block">child</div>';`

** `x += 5` ← то же самое → `x = x + 5`

Но в таком случае оно на каждом круге будет полностью обновлять HTML. Поэтому лучше создать отдельную переменную, на каждом круге в неё добавлять строку, и в конце один раз обновить HTML:

```
let str = "";
for (let i = 0; i < form.num.value; i++) {
  str += '<div class="block">child</div>';
}
parent.innerHTML = str;
```

> Вроде нормально работал вариант с createElement('div') и appendChild ... но как прописать класс...

```
for (let i = 0; i < form.num.value; i++) {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = "block";
  div.textContent = "child";
  parent.appendChild(div);
}
```

---

И, эльфийский вариант:

```
parent.innerHTML = new Array(+form.num.value).fill('<div class="block">child</div>').join('');
```

P.s. обращаю внимание, в циклах for: `i` - число, а `form.num.value` - строка. При сравнении `i < form.num.value` она автоматически превращается в число и всё работает, а здесь была бы ошибка) Поэтому поставлен `+`, он превращает строку в число.